# To find topmost parent window from the child window

Tags: javascript, window, topmost

I use web application

From my main application,I opened child window `C1` and again opened another child window `C2` from `C1`. If i close the the `C1` window, I'm not able to find the top most main application.

Actually i wanted to redirect the Main application to different page if a hyperlink is clicked on the child window.This is working good until i close `C1` which is a parent of `C2`

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: In my web application,opened popup C1 using window.open.Another popup C2 can be opened from C1 on clicking hyperlink. Each popup have parent hyperlink which will redirect the main parent window when user clicked on it. Below is the javascript to find the topmost parent window to redirect. This works well. But it throws error if i close C1 window . because C2 cannot find its parent window. var win = window;
var topWindow = null;
while (win = win.opener) 
{ 
 topWindow = win; 
} 
if(topWindow != 'undefined' && topWindow != null )
{ 
 topWindow.location.href='url link';
}

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

<del>@Mey, without the benefit of seeing your code it will be difficult to pinpoint what your problem is. That said, `window.top` is a reference to the topmost window. It seems to be supported by all major browser (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_top.asp)).</del>

You're absolute correct. This does not work on windows created by `window.open()`. How about this solution: have the opener window set a property on the opened window to keep track of the top most window, immediately after open. That way if any of the intermediate window is closed the opened window already has a reference to the top most window. Let me show you what I mean.

*From top most window:*

```
var c1 = window.open(...);
c1.window.topMost = window;
```

*From first popup:* `c1`

```
var c2 = window.open(...);
c2.window.topMost = window.topMost;
```

*From second popup:* `c2`

```
var c3 = window.open(...);
c3.window.topMost = window.topMost;
```

Now, let say you close `c1` or `c2`, `c3` will still have a reference to `window.topMost`.

Comment: window.top will find the topmost browser when frames are used. But I'm using popup, window.top will not find the main application window.